# Windows batch file - findstr over a variable, looking for string containing percent character and single quote

Tags: windows, batch-file, findstr

In a windows batch file, I am checking the content of a text file given as input - let say a one line text file (test.txt) containing this text:

```
"bla //ID_SCEN='%3' blabla"
```

One of these checks includes looking for a specific string (//ID_SCEN='%3') in a the line with findstr. A test code is the following (test.bat).

```
@echo off
set myLine=
(    
set /p myLine=
)<%1
echo Just found the following line in the input file:
echo %myLine%
echo %myLine% | findstr /C:"//ID_SCEN=^'%%3^'" 1>nul
if errorlevel 1 (
        echo The line %myLine% does not contain //ID_SCEN='%%3'
        echo Too bad, it is compulsory ... I quit
        GOTO:EOF
) else (
    echo Found expected stuff
)
```

For now the output of test.bat test.txt is:

```
Just found the following line in the input file:
"bla //ID_SCEN='%3' blabla"
The line "bla //ID_SCEN='%3' blabla" does not contain //ID_SCEN='%3'
Too bad, it is compulsory ... I quit
```

Can someone help ? It probably has to do with the escape characters - tried various things based on forum posts but did not succeed yet ...

**Accepted answer:**

Replace the `^` escape of single quotes in the search string: `"//ID_SCEN=^'%%3^'"` to `"//ID_SCEN='%%3'"` ... it worked

Best

Comment: In your `FINDSTR` invocation, there's a typo: "ID_SCCEN" instead of "ID_SCEN"

Comment: Thanks --' Corrected the post, however still does not work ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Single quotes don't need escaping in `FINDSTR`. Change...

```
echo %myLine% | findstr /C:"//ID_SCEN=^'%%3^'" 1>nul
```

...to...

```
echo %myLine% | findstr /C:"//ID_SCEN='%%3'" 1>nul
```

...and it works.

However, be aware that `FINDSTR` per se is a mess. It comprises a host of weird edge-cases and undocumented behavior. Have a look at [dbenham](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1012053/dbenham)'s [exhaustive investigation on the matter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8844868/what-are-the-undocumented-features-and-limitations-of-the-windows-findstr-comman) :)

Comment: so better to write your own version of FINDSTR?

Comment: @Zimba I'd rather recommend a Windows port of [`grep`](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/grep.htm).